# Racket Generic Graph Library in Typed Racket

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'm trying to use the generic graph library in typed racket, by importing it with `require/typed`, but I keep getting these weird long errors. Has anyone managed to get the type checker to cooperate with the generic graph library?

```lisp
#lang typed/racket

(require/typed graph
               [#:opaque Graph graph?]
               [unweighted-graph/undirected ((Listof (List Any Any)) -> Graph)]
               [add-edge! (Graph Any Any -> Void)])

(define g : Graph (unweighted-graph/undirected '((1 2) (1 3))))
(add-edge! g 2 3)
```

```
graph?: contract violation
  any-wrap/c: Unable to protect opaque value passed as `Any`
  value: #<unweighted-graph>
  This warning will become an error in a future release.
  in: the 1st argument of
      a part of the or/c of
      (or/c
       struct-predicate-procedure?/c
       (-> Any boolean?))
  contract from: (interface for graph?)
```

Comment: Do you mean `import/typed` or `require/typed`? I'm pretty sure you mean the latter, but this could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Doh! I've been using `require/typed`, the `import` was a typo on my part. Not causing these issues tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't ideal, but there is a workaround:

```lisp
#lang typed/racket

(module wrapper racket
  (provide graph? unweighted-graph/undirected add-edge!)
  (require (prefix-in g: graph))
  (struct graph [g]) ; struct generates the predicate
  (define (unweighted-graph/undirected es) ; wrap output graph
    (graph (g:unweighted-graph/undirected es)))
  (define (add-edge! g a b) ; unwrap input graph
    (g:add-edge! (graph-g g) a b)))

(require/typed 'wrapper
               [#:opaque Graph graph?]
               [unweighted-graph/undirected ((Listof (List Any Any)) -> Graph)]
               [add-edge! (Graph Any Any -> Void)])

(define g : Graph (unweighted-graph/undirected '((1 2) (1 3))))
(add-edge! g 2 3)
```

When Typed Racket `require/typed` sees `#:opaque`, it still needs to treat the predicate you gave, `graph?` as untyped code. But it also needs to use that predicate from untyped code to guard values on the typed-untyped boundary. The `graph?` predicate has the type `(-> Any Boolean)`, so when typed racket calls it with a value from typed code it's passing it with the type `Any`. However, if before this it had a more specific type that involves inputs that must be typed, it still needs to guard against untyped code "using it" in the wrong way, or providing bad untyped inputs.

Adding an opaque struct sidesteps this by making a new `graph?` predicate that doesn't need to "look inside" the value in the same way.